# Can I carry on/check in a child's car seat for free for a flight?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, delta-air-lines, child-safety-seats, jetblue

I am not flying with my child. Instead, I will meet my child at the destination of my flight. I have a small backpack and one carry-on bag, which is free for most airlines. Can I carry on additionally a child's car seat? In fact, it is a booster seat. It will not be used during the flight, but will be used in a rental car in the destination city.

To be more specific, I will fly with Delta and JetBlue this time. If checking in the booster seat would be free, that should be the best solution for me. Can I?

Comment: Does the child have their own seat?

Comment: The child does not fly with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me share my actual experience. I flew with Delta two days ago. I had a small backpack, and a booster seat (I didn't bring another bag).  I flew alone.

They allowed me check in the booster seat for free, and told me that it would have been free if I had another carry-on bag.

It might be that the person was just good, but it seems that they give generosity to child items.

Comment: I also realized that JetBlue currently has one free checked in bag policy.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Delta's Baggage page](http://www.delta.com/traveling_checkin/baggage/carryon/index.jsp) you can check the child seat at curbside and doesn't count as standard baggage allowance.  For JetBlue it's [the same thing](http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webisapi.dll/,/?St=449,E=0000000000055970229,K=9756,Sxi=5,Case=obj%28373795%29).

If the child doesn't fly with you it will count as baggage allowance in a standard way.  They definitely won't let you bring it aboard the aircraft but they may not even let you bring it through security if they don't see a child with you.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Jet Blue that first baggage is free plus they allow to check in a car seat and also a carriage they even let you walk with the baby in the carriage till the flight for your convenience and over there they take it over and you getting it back right when exiting flight.

All The Best!

Comment: This answer appears to relate to flying with a child, whereas the question states "I am not flying with my child".