# How to transport baby/toddler car seat with Transavia?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, children, child-safety-seats

I'll be traveling with 11 month baby on lap. According to [Transavia guidlines](http://www.transavia.com/hv/main/service?id=flying-with-baby&lang=en&country=EU), this means that I can take following:

> 1 piece of hold luggage with a max. weight of 10 kg, such as a
>   suitcase, buggy or pram *(You may take your buggy or pram (maximum weight limit of 7 kg) with you to the gate, where it will be collected and stowed with the hold
>   luggage.)*

However, what I'm intending to take is car seat, either [baby one](http://www.maxi-cosi.com/products/car-seats/infant/pebble/features.aspx) or slightly bigger [toddler one](http://www.maxi-cosi.com/products/car-seats/toddler/priori-sps/features.aspx). First weights 4kg and it's somewhat bigger than hand luggage limit (69x44x39cm vs 55x35x25cm limit), other is 7kg and definitely not hand luggage size.

I'm in doubt how should I transport it. Can it be collected at gate as if it were pram or should I rather pack it as check-in luggage? In later case what would be the best way to pack it?

Comment: Related Question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5687/can-i-carry-on-check-in-a-childs-car-seat-for-free-for-a-flight?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I've got response from Transavia's support:

> For a baby of up to 24 months old, you may only take an infant car
>   seat or umbrella buggy (a maximum of 7 kilograms) along with you on
>   board of the plane. When you board the plane, transavia.com will load
>   the infant car seat or buggy into the cargo hold. During the flight,
>   you have to keep the baby on your lap. Each adult may only have a
>   single baby on his or her lap during the journey. There are no
>   carrycots on board.