# Travel with an empty stroller?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, children

On an international flight (with connections) I am planning on bringing a stroller... with no baby!

Will they make me pay for a 2nd luggage? What am I supposed to do with it?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5687/can-i-carry-on-check-in-a-childs-car-seat-for-free-for-a-flight

Answer (score 4):

Most airlines will let you bring a stroller for free if you have an infant/child, but **only** if you have an infant/child, e.g. [Emirates](http://www.emirates.com/au/english/plan_book/essential_information/baggages/cabin_baggage_rules.aspx), [Qantas](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/checked-baggage/global/en), etc.  So yes, if the stroller puts you over your baggage allowances you will have to pay for excess luggage.

Comment: From my experience most airlines also allow you to check-in a stroller if you are travelling with an older child as well.

Comment: True - From Qantas, "Children up to 12 years of age are permitted one car seat and one collapsible pram, stroller or push chair in addition to the checked baggage allowance."