# Is it possible to check-in a double stroller on a flight?

Tags: air-travel, children

We will be migrating to another country,
and want to bring our double stroller to our new home.
We will be flying with our two kids on the flight.

Our double stroller basically looks like
[this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004DC9TDA),
and it can be folded up to a smaller and more compact size.

Has anyone successfully transported a double stroller on a plane as check-in luggage?
Is there any thing that we should do to make sure that the airline will not refuse to transport our stroller?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25005/travel-with-an-empty-stroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If traveling with young children, **airlines generally allow you to check in strollers for free**.  Unless the dimensions are completely ridiculous even after folding, it should be fine, but ring the airline in question to confirm if you're worried.

Do consider investing in a stroller bag or at least a heavy-duty garbage bag to pack it in, as this reduces the odds of damage if a dangling strap catches onto something etc.  (Many airlines will in fact bag strollers for you for this very reason.)

*Source*: I've personally checked in a [Phil & Teds DOT tandem](https://philandteds.com/au/Products/Push/DOT) with no problems, although this is a stacked, collapsible double stroller and not quite as wide as yours.

Comment: We've checked at the gate both a Graco DuoGlider, and a smaller side-by-side umbrella style stroller.

Comment: The suggestion of stroller bag or heavy-duty garbage bag is a good one.